# Loading a Zend 2 Authentication Adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm writing a custom authentication adapter in Zend Framework 2.

module/Application/src/Application/Auth/Adapter/Auth_Adapter.php -

```
namespace Application\Auth;

use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\Result;

class Auth_Adapter implements AdapterInterface {
...
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but no classes can seem to find my new adapter. I've tried moving it into an autoloaded path (the Application/Controller directory) with no luck either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming your namespaces are invalid. Given the path "module/Application/src/Application/Auth/Adapter/Auth_Adapter.php"

Try:

```
namespace Application\Auth\Adapter;
```